# Response Document with Computed Fields

Tags: xpages, response, parent-child

I'm simply trying to create a response document that pulls in fields (data) from the parent document. This data needs to also save with the response document (which is separate) so I couldn't just use "read only" fields. I've got my computed fields tied to the fields on the parent document, but when the response document displays, the fields aren't pulled in.

I'm wondering if it's not getting the ParentID correctly? I'm using this code on my "Respond" button to create the response document:

```
document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()
```

Comment: Show us the complete code of your "Respond" button, please and an example for a field definition in respond's XPage.

Comment: It's just a button with a Create Document Response action. It's opening my Review XPage (which is the response). The parent document has fields such as "Form Number" "Title" "Description" and "Department". The data entered in those fields on the parent document need to be displayed on the response document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action "Create Response Document" creates only the response document and adds the $REF item. If you want to copy fields from parent document then you have to copy them manually. You can do that in beforePageLoad event:

```xml
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" />
</xp:this.data>
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var parentDoc = database.getDocumentByUNID(document1.getParentId()); 
    document1.setValue("Title", parentDoc.getItemValue("Title"))
    document1.setValue("Description", parentDoc.getItemValue("Description"))
    }]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

This way fields get copied to response document. You can show the fields in response's XPages like usually:

```xml
<xp:text
    id="computedField1"
    value="#{document1.Title}">
</xp:text>
```

Comment: What also might work (haven't tried it): If your form has all the needed formulas in the default values and the property "inherit" selected and the data source "compute on load" it might work too. I wouldn't recommend that approach since it has too many moving parts