# Xpages - response document - inherit values

Tags: response, xpages, parent-child, lotus-notes

I've just stumbled across this post, which gives an explanation on how to inherit values from a parent document. I can't get it to work though. Would anyone be able to explain exactly how and where to put this code into the xpage for the response document?

[Response Document with Computed Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953922/response-document-with-computed-fields/20960065#20960065)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The post you link to puts the code in the beforePageLoad event on the XPages for the response document. Please update your question with more details of what your problem is and please include code snippets that show what you have tried so far

Comment: Thanks @PerHenrikLausten - the code is exactly as you put it:

`code`<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" />
</xp:this.data>
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var parentDoc = database.getDocumentByUNID(document1.getParentId()); 
    document1.setValue("SHERef", parentDoc.getItemValue("RefNo"))
    }]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>

I'm just not sure exactly where to enter this code on the "beforePageLoad" event. Do I add it as an action or under "script editor"?

Then I'll have the problem of where to enter the code for the field....

Comment: You add the 'document1' data source in the usual data source section. You then add the server side Javascript code in the beforePageLoad event using the script editor.
If you to to the source of your XPages using "Source" instead of "Design" your code should then look similar to the code in the linked answer.

Comment: So yep the "document1" data source is already there which is for the response document.

In the "beforePageLoad" script editor box I think you only need to put the following is that correct? I get errors if I put the full code in there?

var parentDoc = database.getDocumentByUNID(document1.getParentId()); 
document1.setValue("SHERef", parentDoc.getItemValue("RefNo"))

When I look at the source it then looks as you posted originally.

I think I'm happy with that part now, the challenge is displaying the inherited value...

Comment: Yes, your code is now correct. Now you just need to add two fields. I will add an answer

Comment: @Lambey keep in mind that unless you are coexisting with a notes client app, XPages doesn't need to use actual "response" documents.  You can store related (child) documents as main documents, even store them in a seperate .nsf all together.  lot of options really compared to a notes client application.

Answer (score 3):

Put the server side Javascript code in the beforePageLoad event using the script editor. If you to to the source of your XPages using "Source" instead of "Design" your code should then look similar to the code in the linked answer.

You can then display the value in the SHERef field by adding a computed text field:

```
<xp:text id="valueOfSHERef" value="#{document1.SHERef}"></xp:text>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help!
The value is populated for existing documents, but when I create a new response I get the following error:

"Error 500
Unexpected error condition"

So for documents I have previously created it does work, but not for new ones....any idea?

Comment: Check your XPages log file for details of the error. Maybe parentDoc is null since document1.getParentId() is empty until the response document has been saved? You can check for this in your code.